# Why does android's CompoundButton.setOnLoadCompleteListener swap button Id when set to true in specific order

Tags: android, soundpool

Like the title states, when I set a switch through the UI to play my_sound1 first everything works as expected, but if click the switch for my_sound2 first it's like the buttonId gets swapped for the two.

I've gone over and over this and can't seem to find another instance where someone has the same problem.  At first I thought it was a bug in soundpool, but now I'm pretty sure it's in the OnCheckedChangeListener code.

If I play the "Crickets" first the app acts the way I want it to.  But if I play the "Frogs" first it causes the program to act like the switch Id's are swapped. I've tested it in android 4.1.2, 5.1.1, 7.1.1 and it happens in all three.

Did I not setup the switches correctly?  Is this a bug in android?

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int my_sound1;
private int my_sound2;

boolean plays1 = false, plays2 = false, loaded_crickets = false, loaded_frogs = false;
float actVolume, maxVolume, volume;
AudioManager audioManager;

private Switch crickets_switch;
private Switch frogs_switch;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // AudioManager audio settings for adjusting the volume
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    actVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volume = actVolume / maxVolume;

    //Hardware buttons setting to adjust the media sound
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        soundPool = (new SoundPool.Builder()).setMaxStreams(2).build();
    }else{
        soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    my_sound1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.crickets, 1);
    my_sound2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.frogs, 2);

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
            if (sampleId == my_sound1) { loaded_crickets = true; }
            if (sampleId == my_sound2) { loaded_frogs = true; }
        }
    });

    crickets_switch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    frogs_switch = findViewById(R.id.switch2);

    crickets_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton crickets_switch, boolean isCheckedCrickets) {
            if (isCheckedCrickets) {
                if (loaded_crickets && !plays1) {
                    soundPool.play(my_sound1, volume, volume, 1, -1, 1f);
                    plays1 = true;
                } else {
                    soundPool.resume(my_sound1);
                }
            }
            if (!isCheckedCrickets && plays1 == true) {
                soundPool.pause(my_sound1);
            }
        }
    });

    frogs_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton frogs_switch, boolean isCheckedFrogs) {
            if (isCheckedFrogs) {
                if (loaded_frogs && !plays2) {
                    soundPool.play(my_sound2, volume, volume, 2, -1, 1f);
                    plays2 = true;
                } else {
                    soundPool.resume(my_sound2);
                }
            }
            if (!isCheckedFrogs && plays2 == true) {
                soundPool.pause(my_sound2);
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="173dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/crickets"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/switch2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="176dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/frogs"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `But if I play the "Frogs" first it causes the program to act like the switch Id's are swapped.`?

Comment: did you try to setup some breakpoints in your both `onCheckedChanged` methods and run a [debug session](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) with your app? did you notice some strange behavior?

Comment: BTW it looks like you are going to try to resume playing `my_sound1 ` when `loaded_crickets` is false.

Comment: To trace as @pskink suggested is a good idea. You can also extract the logic in a business logic class and run some unit test. It is very easy now with Android Studio and you will see if your logic is correct.

Comment: @kingston You're right, it does try to resume when loaded_crickets is false. I'll fix that. What I mean by playing "Frogs" first, is that the switches swap what sounds they control, "Crickets" will start controlling the frog sound and "Frogs" will start controlling the crickets sound.  I will set some break points and debug as pskink suggested.